# Notation: $F^{*m}$ for field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Quick question (which is surprisingly hard to Google): if $F$ is a field, what is $F^{*m}$? I suspect it's the $m$-th powers of the elements of the multiplicative group $F^*$, so $\{ x^m : x \in F^* \}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Probably, but it could also be the set of $m$-tuples of elements of $F^*$. There is no way to know with such little context.

Comment: You're right and the notation is really ambiguous.

Comment: Hmm, I know that for $H$ a subgroup of $F^{*}$, that $H \cap F^{*m}$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, so I guess it's what I guessed then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is ambigous. It might be, as you write
$$F^{*m} = \{x^m \mid x\in F^*\},$$
but also the $m$-fold cartesian product of the unit group
$$F^{*m} = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \mid x_1,\ldots,x_m\in F^*\}.$$

You should check the context to find out what the meaning is in your case.

Comment: In this context, I guess the only semantics that fit are the $m$-th powers, but good to know the notation is ambiguous. Is this notation also common for arbitrary groups $G$, i.e. $G^m = \{ x^m : x \in G \}$?

Comment: @Mark: very common notation for groups is $GH = \{gh \mid g\in G, h\in H\}$. Because of the ambiguity, the notation $G^m$ for $\{g^m \mid g\in G\}$ is is not that frequent, but certainly possible.